# $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be continuous ; then is there a non-empty proper closed $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $ A \subseteq f(A)$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a continuous function ; then is it true that there is a non-empty proper closed subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ such that $ A \subseteq f(A)$ ?

I can show that if $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous then there is a non-empty proper closed subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ such that $ f(A) \subseteq A$ ; but I have no idea on what happens if we want a reverse inclusion . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not true. In fact let me give an example for $\mathbb R$ already. Let $f$ be a strictly increasing function bounded from below by $C$ and let $f(x)>x$ (there are plenty of functions like this). Now towards contradiction let $A$ be one of the subsets you desire. $A$ has a minimal point $p$ as the image of $f$ is bounded from below (and $A$ is closed). Now the point $f(p)$ is the minimal point of the image of $A$ as $f$ is increasing and $f(p)>p$. In particular $p$ is not in $f(A)$.

Comment: The domain and range of $f$ is $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R.$ What do you mean by $f(x)>x$?

Comment: Well the statement is false for R. It is easy to extend to a counterexample for any dimension (use this f on all coordinates for example)

Comment: I see what you mean now.  But in $\mathbb R^2,$  the closed set $\{(x,y): 0<x \land 0<y \land xy\geq 1\}$  has no minimum first or second co-ordinate

Comment: Maybe that's not the easiest way to extend the counterexample. Probably easier to first project to the x-axis :)

Comment: For $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, we have $e^x$, for instance. How would you generalise that function to $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: (x,y) to (e^x,0) works

Comment: Ahh, I think I had something reversed when thinking about this. You're right, it is easy to generalise from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Arthur. Yes.$ F(x,y)=(e^x,0)$ works. But the $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ in the Answer should have an additional condition: $\inf (f(x)-x)>0.$ This takes care of the case  where $\phi\ne A\subset  \mathbb R^2$ is closed but $\min \{x:(x,y)\in A\}$ does not exist, because any $(x,y)\in A$ with $x$ close enough to $\inf \{x:(x,y)\in A\}$ will not be in $f(A)$.

Comment: (f(x),f(y)) also works and no extra condition is needed (while I realized after posting my first comment it is significantly harder to prove than (f(x),0), it is a fun exercise :) and I might still have missed a very easy way to do it).